# toggle sidebar when button in navbar is clicked in ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ember.js

I have two components:

```
{{pc-sidebar}}
{{pc-navbar action='toggleSidebar'}}
```

Inside pc-navbar, i have a button that i want toggle an sidebar--active class:

```
<button {{action 'toggle'}}>toggle sidebar</button>
```

and in the pc-navbar.js, i have the following:

```
  isOpen: true,
  actions: {
    toggle () {
        this.toggleProperty('isOpen');
        this.sendAction('action', this.get('isOpen'));
    }
  }
```

So.. the default value of sidebar is open, and when i click, i want switch for the next state.. true or false, depending on the previous state.

So.. i change the default value and send to my application controller:

```
  actions: {
    toggleSidebar (nextState) {
      console.log(nextState);
    }
  }
```

Now.. how can i grap the sidebar and toggle the class?? I'm a little lost here.. Am i doing this write?

In my pc-sidebar.js i have:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'aside',
  classNames: ['sidebar', 'sidebar--active']
});
```

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use both the components in one route say `aroute`,You can have the property `isOpen` in `aroute`. You can pass this property to both the components, Then you can observe it in `pc-sidebar` if it was modified in `pc-navbar`.

Comment: hm.. could you give me some code example? I think i didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a common property on the route/controller that the components are sitting in and an action to toggle this property.

```
//index.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isOpen: false,
  actions: {
    toggleOpen: function() {
      this.toggleProperty('isOpen');
    }
});
```

In your template:

```
//index.hbs
{{component-one toggleOpen="toggleOpen"}}
{{component-two isOpen=isOpen}}
```

One component needs to be aware of the property so it knows when to open, the other just wants to send an action to open/close it.

```
//component-one.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    toggleOpen: function() {
      this.sendAction('toggleOpen');
    }
});
```

Then just trigger the action from component-one, component-two has a bound property it can use to either show or hide.